# Inclusive Date Range check in Joda Time

Tags: java, date, datetime, jodatime

I am using Joda Time 2.1 library.

I have written a method to compare if a given date is between a date range of not. I want it to be inclusive to the start date and end date.I have used `LocalDate` as I don't want to consider the time part only date part.

Below is the code for it.

```
isDateBetweenRange(LocalDate start,LocalDate end,LocalDate target){

       System.out.println("Start Date : "
              +start.toDateTimeAtStartOfDay(DateTimeZone.forID("EST"));

       System.out.println("Target Date : "
              +targettoDateTimeAtStartOfDay(DateTimeZone.forID("EST"));

       System.out.println("End Date : "
              +end.toDateTimeAtStartOfDay(DateTimeZone.forID("EST"));

       System.out.println(target.isAfter(start));

       System.out.println(target.isBefore(end));
}
```

The output of above method is :

```
Start Date: 2012-11-20T00:00:00.000-05:00
Target Date: 2012-11-20T00:00:00.000-05:00
End Date : 2012-11-21T00:00:00.000-05:00
target.isAfter(start) : false
target.isBefore(end) : true
```

My problem is `target.isAfter(start)` is false even if the `target` date and `start` are having the same values.

I want that `target >= start` but here it considers only `target > start`.
I want it inclusive.

Does it mean that `isAfter` method finds a match exclusively ?

I have gone through the javadoc for Joda Time, but didn't found anything about it.

Comment: Check my answer in similar thread as to an interval of LocalDates:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/14998753/1367432

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Yes, `isAfter` is exclusive, otherwise it should probably have been named `isEqualOrAfter` or something similar.

Solution: Use "not before" instead of "after", and "not after" instead of "before".

```
boolean isBetweenInclusive(LocalDate start, LocalDate end, LocalDate target) {
    return !target.isBefore(start) && !target.isAfter(end);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

Joda-Time has been supplanted by the *java.time* classes and the *ThreeTen-Extra* project.

The `LocalDateRange` and `Interval` classes representing a span-of-time use the Half-Open definition. So, asking if the beginning is contained returns `true`.

```
LocalDateRange.of(                     // `org.threeten.extra.LocalDateRange` class represents a pair of `LocalDate` objects as a date range.
    LocalDate.of( 2018, 8 , 2 ) ,      // `java.time.LocalDate` class represents a date-only value, without time-of-day and without time zone.
    LocalDate.of( 2018 , 8 , 20 ) 
)                                      // Returns a `LocalDateRange` object.
.contains(
    LocalDate.now()                    // Capture the current date as seen in the wall-clock time used by the people of the JVM’s current default time zone.
)
```

> true

## java.time

FYI, the [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project is now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), with the team advising migration to the [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. See [Tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

### Date-only

Apparently you may care about the date and not the time-of-day. If so, use [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class.

For managing a date range, add the [*ThreeTen-Extra*](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) library to your project. This gives you access to the [`LocalDateRange`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/LocalDateRange.html) class.

That class offers several methods for comparison: `abuts`, [`contains`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/LocalDateRange.html#contains-java.time.LocalDate-), `encloses`, `equals`, `intersection`, `isBefore`, `isAfter`, `isConnected`, [`overlaps`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/LocalDateRange.html), `span`, and `union`.

```
LocalDateRange r = 
    LocalDateRange.of( 
        LocalDate.of( 2018, 8 , 2 ) , 
        LocalDate.of( 2018 , 8 , 20 ) 
    ) 
;

LocalDate target = LocalDate.now( ZoneId.of( "Africa/Tunis" ) ) ;  // Capture the current date as seen in the wall-clock time used by the people of a particular time zone.
boolean contains = r.contains( target ) ;
```

### Date-time

If you care about the date and the time-of-day in a particular time zone, use `ZonedDateTime` class.

Start with your `LocalDate`, and let that class determine the first moment of the day. The day does *not* always start at 00:00:00 because of anomalies such as *Daylight Saving Time (DST)*.

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `continent/region`, such as [`America/Montreal`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal), [`Africa/Casablanca`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Africa/Casablanca), or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 3-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ;  // Or "America/New_York", etc.
ZonedDateTime zdtStart = LocalDate.of( 2018, 8 , 2 ).atStartOfDay( z ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdtStop = LocalDate.of( 2018, 8 , 20 ).atStartOfDay( z ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdtTarget = ZonedDateTime.now( z ) ;
```

Represent a range with the `Interval` from *ThreeTen-Extra*. This class represents a pair of `Instant` objects. An `Instant` is a moment in UTC, always in UTC. We can easily adjust from our zoned moment to UTC by simply extracting an `Instant`. Same moment, same point on the timeline, different wall-clock time.

```
Instant instantStart = zdtStart.toInstant() ;
Instant instantStop = zdtStop.toInstant() ;
Instant instantTarget = zdtTarget.toInstant() ;

Interval interval = Interval.of( instantStart , intervalStop ) ;
boolean contains = interval.contains( instantTarget ) ;
```

## Half-Open

The best approach to defining a span-of-time is generally the *Half-Open* approach. This means the beginning is *inclusive* while the ending is *exclusive*.

The comparisons in the `ThreeTen-Extra` range classes seen above (`LocalDateRange` & `Interval`) both use Half-Open approach. So asking if the starting date or starting moment is contained in the range results in a `true`.

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).