# Jodatime overlap method not checking equals

Tags: java, date, jodatime, overlap

For finding the overlap of two date ranges i understand we need something like.

```
(thisStart <= otherEnd ) && (otherStart <= thisEnd)
```

But inside [the overlaps method from Joda Time](https://github.com/JodaOrg/joda-time/blob/acff94148b2110b95f7aeae6a1bdcafb756061f0/src/main/java/org/joda/time/base/AbstractInterval.java#L239) I see

```
thisStart < otherEnd && otherStart < thisEnd
```

This wont cover certain overlap conditions. Is there any other method which cover overlap using **<=**

Comment: Note that JodaTime interval is inclusive at the start and exclusive at the end, i.e. `start <= x < end`.

Comment: when thisStart = otherEnd = otherStart

Comment: See also: [Inclusive Date Range Check in Joda Time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13583944/inclusive-date-range-check-in-joda-time?rq=1)

Comment: @Jesper I did see your answer. Using before and after is one way to meet my requirement. I was just wondering why overlap won't do it.

Answer (score 1):

`start` and `end` designate *instants* in time.  In Joda (and any sane implementation of a time range) a range is half-open on the right, i.e. it does not include the end-instant.

Under those conditions, the test in the Joda library is correct.

If you're still unconvinced, try to come up with a counterexample where overlap is not detected correctly.

Comment: I have shared a scenario in the comments. One can say that's not a range per se. But i believe its very valid for a lot of common business scenarios.

Comment: In other words, Garrison is saying the Half-Open approach means the beginning is *inclusive* while the ending is *exclusive*. This is a common, and wise, approach to define spans of time.