# Is there an alternative for Joda-Time interval in Java, which works as end time inclusive

Tags: java, jodatime

I am trying to check if a particular date falls within a certain date range. I came across Joda Time interval in Java. But it works as end time exclusive.

So is there an alternative which functions as end time inclusive

Comment: What's your exact use case? Can you describe it a little more in detail? Or could you show us the code with joda that doesn't do what's desired?

Comment: See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13584000/8621733 Strict `<` can be negated to `>=` so this might be useful.

Comment: Does your date have year, month of year and day of month only or are you talking about a `java.util.Date`?

Comment: Read this post, it contains great info on how to use java.time: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32437550/whats-the-difference-between-instant-and-localdatetime

Answer (score 7):

## *java.time*

I recommend you use [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html)<sup>*</sup>.

Quoted below is a notice at the [home page of Joda-Time](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/):

> Note that from Java SE 8 onwards, users are asked to migrate to java.time (JSR-310) - a core part of the JDK which replaces this project.

You can use `!date.isAfter` where `date` is a reference to `LocalDate`  e.g.

```
import java.time.LocalDate;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LocalDate start = LocalDate.of(2021, 5, 10);
        LocalDate end = LocalDate.of(2021, 6, 10);
        for (LocalDate date = start; !date.isAfter(end); date = date.plusDays(1)) {
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

Learn more about the modern Date-Time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

---

<sup>* For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7. If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).</sup>

Comment: Solid Answer. Further tip: The [`LocalDateRange`](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org.threeten.extra/org/threeten/extra/LocalDateRange.html) class in the [*ThreeTen-Extra*](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) library has methods to treat the ending as inclusive, using "closed" terminology, as in full-closed versus half-open. But I recommend always working with half-open to keep your logic consistent. I have seen many miscommunications amongst businesspeople regarding fully-closed versus half-open. And, using half-open enables time spans that neatly abut.