# Equivalent to jodatime Interval in Java 8 Date and Time API

Tags: jodatime, java-8

The Java 8 way of dealing with time seems to have improved so much that I start to think about replacing [jodatime](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) in some cases. But what I am missing is an equivalent to the [Interval](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/Interval.html) class.

I haven't dug too deep into Java 8 yet, so I might have missed something there. Does anyone have ideas on how intervals could be best dealt with?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

No way, the Joda class `Interval` does not exist in JSR-310. The concepts of `Duration`, `Period` etc. denotes temporal amounts without being bound to fixed points in time while an interval has a fixed start and fixed end on the timeline.

By the way, this question is not new and a [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22150722/is-there-a-class-in-java-time-comparable-to-the-joda-time-interval/22152890#22152890). On the other SO-link you can also find a similar answer direct from JodaTime-project-leader.

Comment: Seems I keep sticking with joda. It's not such a bad thing anyway. Thanks for the answer.