# Java 8 class to represent time intervals

Tags: java, date, time

Java 8 introduced a new Time & Date API, with classes like `Period` or `Duration`.

Now I'm looking for a class to represent date intervals, e.g. "from 4th August 2016 to 8th August 2016" and answer the question: do these intervals overlap. `Period` doesn't seem to satisfy this, since it works in an affine way, not knowing where the interval has started, only how long it takes.

Is there any Java 8 standard library class to suit my needs? Or do I have to write my own?

Comment: What are you trying to do with the start and end date time? Are you trying to work out the amount of time between the two?

Comment: You could try [Joda time interval](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/Interval.html). Java 8 doesn't have an equivalent: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22886030/equivalent-to-jodatime-interval-in-java-8-date-and-time-api

Comment: Java 8 has no interval class, but you might find my library interesting: [Time4J](http://time4j.net/javadoc-en/net/time4j/range/package-summary.html) It offers conversions for Java-8-types.

Comment: Shouldn't `Duration` come close to what you need?

Comment: I'm not allowed to use any 3rd-party libs. I'll have `n` entries that some resource is reserved between two dates and have to find out whether will be free during some interval.

Comment: If 3rd-party-libs are not allowed then you have to create your own interval class from the scratch. Sorry for you. A simple approach would be a class with start and end date as members and defining some methods for creation, overlap-query, start- and end-query and the usual equals()-hashCode()-toString()-stuff.

Comment: You could always copy & paste a library (not recommended but since you cannot use a 3rd party), which allows that (i.e., look at the license). There are several Interval (sometimes also called Range) implementations, e.g., Guava (https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/RangesExplained or Breinify (https://github.com/Breinify/brein-time-utilities/blob/master/docs/Interval.md)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could resolve the date down into a `long` and use an [IntervalTree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree). [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11189080/823393)'s one I made earlier.