# Time range with START and END in Java

Tags: java, time

Is there any standard Java implementation to represent a time range with **FROM** and **TO**? Actually I am using the following class.

I also looked at `Instant.range()` or `Period`, which are both not defining a time range or span, but calculating the duration of a period instead of saving the exact time range with **FROM** and **TO**.

```
public class TimeRange {

  private Instant from, to;

  public TimeRange(Instant from, Instant to) {
     this.from = from;
     this.to = to;
  }

  public Instant getFrom() {
     return from;
  }

  public void setFrom(Instant from) {
     this.from = from;
  }

  public Instant getTo() {
     return to;
  }

  public void setTo(Instant to) {
     this.to = to;
  }

  public boolean isProperlySet() {
     return from != null && to != null;
  }
}
```

Comment: The [Threeten-extra library](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) contains an [Interval](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html) class. Does that cover your need?

Comment: I find the method `isProperlySet()` weird. Are you doing this for every object, that contains settable members? Why not just throwing or let throw an `Exception`?

Comment: Or my lib Time4J with even more features, see [API](http://time4j.net/javadoc-en/net/time4j/range/SimpleInterval.html#between-java.time.Instant-java.time.Instant-).

Comment: I agree with @HerrDerb. Verify the received `Instant`s in the constructor, e.g. `this.from = Objects.requireNonNull(from);`.

Comment: @Henrik: that won't work because the objects are not final

Comment: Ah, the setters. I need more coffee. :)

Comment: @Herr Derb: The method can be used to do an ondemand validation from external code, so its convenient. Exceptions might be code in most cases, but here i want to check before instead of receiving exceptions to determine an detailed error cause which can be shown to the user

Comment: I saw library, but isn't there a "JAVA-Standard" way to do this? I think its a common use case...

Comment: @alex But still, you are using `isProperlySet()` so the developer can make sure that he is using this object correctly. That is a job for `Exceptions` and a correct `javaDoc`.

Comment: `isProperlySet` avoids  forcing the developer to do nullchecks, exception handling would force a lot unnecessary boiler plate code, so i would disagree here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a class in java.time comparable to the Joda-Time Interval?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22150722/is-there-a-class-in-java-time-comparable-to-the-joda-time-interval)